# Django NoReverseMatch, not a registered namespace

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following link in my project template:

```
<li><a id="toggleLogin" href= "{% url 'login' %}" onclick="toggleLogin();" ><span>Login</span></a></li> <!-- login app
-->
```

the project **url** is:

```
url(r'^login/',loginViews.user_login,name='login'),
```

the application **url** is:

```
url(r'^$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
```

and the application **view** is:

```
def user_login(request):
    """User at login view """
    #
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # First get the username and password supplied
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        # Django's built-in authentication function:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # If we have a user
        if user:
            #Check it the account is active
            if user.is_active:
                # Log the user in.
                login(request,user)
                # Send the user back to some page.
                # In this case their homepage.
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                # If account is not active:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is not active.")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        #Nothing has been provided for username or password.
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

But once the linked clicked, it returns the following django error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /login/
'login_app' is not a registered namespace
```

should this namespace be registered in the project url file as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right!
so the proper way would be:

**html**:

```
<li><a id="toggleLogin" href= "{% url 'login_app:user_login' %}" onclick="toggleLogin();"
```

project **url**:

```
url(r'^login/',include('login_app.urls',namespace='login_app')),
```

and application **url**:

```
url(r'^$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
```

Although it leads to another question regarding the execution of the inline javascript function. But I will create a new question for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the "application url" at all. You have defined the URL entirely in the project URL (as `login`), so no [namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) is created. Normally you would use [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) to link to the app urls, but you're not doing that.